# WSO2 API Manager - Make the API Store Default Component

Tags: api, wso2, haproxy, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 1.8 and it has been deployed on the cloud according [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+HAProxy) with a HAProxy. I have been given a IP `https://192.168.X.XYZ` to access the API Manager which is the IP given to the cloud instance.

My problem is when I type `https://192.168.X.XYZ`, it loads the publisher, what I want to do is load the API store rather than loading the publisher. Basic idea is that a domain will be mapped to the above IP address. So when an user type the domain user should be shown the API Store not the API Publisher.

`https://192.168.X.XYZ`  ->  `https://myapistore.com`

How can I configure API store to be loaded rather than the API Publisher in WSO2 API Manager 1.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<AM_HOME>/repository/components/plugins` directory, there is a bundle called "org.wso2.am.styles_1.x.x.jar". Open this jar and find its `component.xml` file which resides in `META-INF` directory. You should notice that `default-context` has been pointed to `publisher`. Change it to `store` as follows and update the jar.

```
<context>
       <context-id>default-context</context-id>
       <context-name>store</context-name>
       <protocol>http</protocol>
       <description>API Publisher Default Context</description>
</context>
```

After doing the above restart the server.

Now, if you try to access the root URL of the server https://192.168.X.XYZ, it will be redirected to the API Store (https://192.168.X.XYZ/store/).